# Kafka Connect with Spring Framework

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-integration, apache-kafka-connect

Is anyone aware of any Spring Boot integration with Kafka Connect? There is a spring-kafka project that I think gives a nice integration with Kafka clients but not connect and streams APIs.

Comment: what do you want to do with kafka connect & spring ?

Answer (score 0):

KConnect itself is a different Client, you cannot add spring to it. By doing so you would end up creating your own client, which cannot be termed as KConnect. If you are intending to integrate KConnect plugins with spring, its a difficult task but should be still possible, but I won't recommend it as plugins should be light in terms of initialization and run time. Also KConnect is not meant hold any business logic, if there is no business logic then standard plugins should be able to full fill your needs.

However KStreams can be integrated with spring. It is a simple as creating a bean object. Here is a sample

```
public class SampleStream {

@Autowired
CustomBean myBean;

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleStream.class);

public SampleStream() {
    KafkaStreams stream = getStream();
    LOG.info("Starting Stream {}", stream);

    stream.start();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(stream::close));
}

private KafkaStreams getStream(){

    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, String> requestStream = builder.stream("REQUEST_TOPIC");

    KStream<String, String> responseStream = requestStream.flatMap((key, request) -> {
         myBean.process(request)
        //custom logic
    });

    responseStream.to("RESPONSE_TOPIC");

    return new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), getStreamProperties());
}


private Properties getStreamProperties() {
    String defaultKeySerdes = Serdes.StringSerde.class.getName();
    String defaultValueSerdes = Serdes.StringSerde.class.getName();
    String defaultExceptionHandler = LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class.getName();

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, this.getClass().toString());
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka.com:9092");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, defaultKeySerdes);
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, defaultValueSerdes);
    properties.put(GenericMessagingConstants.KAFKA_DESERIALIZER_VALUE_CLASS_CONFIG, String.class.getName());
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, defaultExceptionHandler);
    ....
    return properties;
    }
}
```

Create Bean in application-context as below,

```
<bean id="sampleStream" class="SampleStream"/>
```

Answering this as it took some time to figure this out.